# "+1 for bla bla bla" comments

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, up-votes

I can't tell you how many times I've seen a comment that simply says "+1 for [insert quote from answer]". Here are a few examples:

1. [Why do we have reinterpret_cast in C++ when two chained static_cast can do its job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025843/why-do-we-have-reinterpret-cast-in-c-when-two-chained-static-cast-can-do-its?rq=1#comment5621402_5026218)
2. [Why do we have reinterpret_cast in C++ when two chained static_cast can do its job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025843/why-do-we-have-reinterpret-cast-in-c-when-two-chained-static-cast-can-do-its?rq=1#comment5660567_5026001) (different comment)
3. [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast?lq=1#comment1869951_1255015)

Do comments like these contribute to the overall good of the stackoverflow community?

Comment: -1 because your face.

Comment: -1 because your mom. @mikeTheLiar +1 because your awesome.

Comment: -1 not enough jquery

Comment: -1 because users can have comments match `/^[+-]\d+$/` as many times as they'd like, and there's nothing you will ever be able to do about it.

Comment: I find it funny that every single comment on this page begins with either "+" or "-"

Comment: -1 @Joel get out of here you contrary person!

Comment: I sometimes see such comments used to draw attention to an important part of a long answer. In such cases, it may be appropriate to edit the answer to make the point stand out more so that the comment is no longer required.

Comment: -1 What's with the serious comment @hammar?

Comment: @Joel: And then you go and break it... -1

Comment: -1 @BoltClock'saUnicorn you put the number *before* the post text, silly.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: I am a unicorn, I am not bound by absurd human conventions. -1

Comment: +1 @BoltClock'saUnicorn Just because you're a unicorn doesn't mean you get to break the rules.... oh wait, it does. Can I join your club?

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with this post, but I voted to delete since it's a duplicate and the comments make it mostly noise compared to the other threads

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The examples you have given don't add much to pretty much every user except for the answer poster - a bit of info so they know why they got a specific upvote (though not even that, on occasion).

Flag as "not constructive / off-topic".

Comment: +1 for "Flag as 'not constructive / off-topic'."

Comment: +1 such comments are only noise.

Comment: +1 for bla bla bla

Comment: +1 to community members to demonstrate what comments should be flagged.

Comment: +42 for 5 +1 Comments and 3 actual upvotes.

Comment: +1 for +1 comments. +1ception

Comment: +1 to downvoters who can't explain why they disagree.

Comment: -1 because "too chatty" flag feels more appropriate than NC/OT

Comment: +½ since I'm late to the party

Comment: +½ as a rounding value to prior comment

Comment: -1 because you're probably using floating point anyway

Comment: +π just because

Comment: +i this post is unreal

Comment: +e because it is all natural without preservatives or artificial colourings

Comment: C-C-C-C-COMBO BREAKER

Comment: Also, @Servy +1 for your +1